# How do you find or know where the "non-owned" entity type when trying to create a migration?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have the following classes:

1. JobSeeker which owns a CreditCard which has a CreditCardType

   ```
    public class JobSeeker : Entity
    {
        private readonly List<CreditCard> _creditCards;        
        public IEnumerable<CreditCard> CreditCards => _creditCards.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public class CreditCard : Entity
    {
        public CreditCardType CardType { get { return CreditCardType.From(_creditCardTypeID); } private set { } }
        private readonly int _creditCardTypeID;}


    public class CreditCardType : Enumeration
    {
        public static readonly CreditCardType Amex = new CreditCardType(1, nameof(Amex).ToLowerInvariant());

        public static readonly CreditCardType Visa = new CreditCardType(2, nameof(Visa).ToLowerInvariant());

        public static readonly CreditCardType MasterCard = new CreditCardType(3, nameof(MasterCard).ToLowerInvariant());

        public static IEnumerable<CreditCardType> List() => new[] { Amex, Visa, MasterCard };}
   ```

My DBContext Configs are:

```
class JobSeekerEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobSeeker>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobSeeker> jsConfiguration)
    {
        if (jsConfiguration == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsConfiguration));
        }

        // Build the model
        jsConfiguration.OwnsOne(s => s.CompleteName);
        jsConfiguration.OwnsOne(s => s.HomeAddress);
        jsConfiguration.OwnsOne(s => s.BillingAddress);
        jsConfiguration.OwnsOne(s => s.EmAddress);
        jsConfiguration.OwnsOne(s => s.PersonalPhoneNumber);

        jsConfiguration.OwnsMany(a => a.CreditCards);

        //jsConfiguration.HasMany<CreditCard>().WithOne(JobSeeker).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


        jsConfiguration.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
        jsConfiguration.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
    }
}

class CreditCardTypeEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CreditCard>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CreditCard> ccConfiguration)
    {
        if (ccConfiguration == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ccConfiguration));
        }

        // Build the model
        ccConfiguration.HasOne(o => o.CardType).WithMany().HasForeignKey("_creditCardTypeID");

        ccConfiguration.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
        ccConfiguration.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");

    }
}

class CreditCardEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CreditCardType>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CreditCardType> cctConfiguration)
    {
        if (cctConfiguration == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cctConfiguration));
        }

        // Build the model
        cctConfiguration.ToTable("CreditCardTypes");

        cctConfiguration.HasKey(o => o.Id);

        cctConfiguration.Property(o => o.Id)
            .HasDefaultValue(1)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .IsRequired();

        cctConfiguration.Property(o => o.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(200)
            .IsRequired();

        cctConfiguration.HasData(
                new { Id = 1, Name = "Amex" },
                new { Id = 2, Name = "Visa" },
                new { Id = 3, Name = "MasterCard" });


    }
}
```

My DB Context is:

```
public class JobSeekerContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private static readonly Type[] EnumerationTypes = { typeof(CreditCardType) };

    public const string DEFAULT_SCHEMA = "jobseeker";

    private readonly ILoggerFactory MyConsoleLoggerFactory;

    private readonly IMediator Mediator;

    public DbSet<JobSeeker> JobSeekers { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CreditCardType> CreditCardTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));
        }

        // Build the model
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CreditCardTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CreditCardEntityTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobSeekerEntityTypeConfiguration());
```

}

When I run the migration I get the following error: "The type 'CreditCard' cannot be marked as owned because a non-owned entity type with the same name already exists."

Where is CreditCard marked as non-owned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is `CreditCard` marked as non-owned?

In `JobSeekerContext` here

```cs
public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
```

and here

```cs
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CreditCardTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());
```

and the whole (misleadingly named) `CreditCardTypeEntityTypeConfiguration` class since it is `IEntityTypeConfiguration<CreditCard>`.

---

[Owned entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) are special entities which are configured, queried and updated *only* through *owner*.

Here is the excerpt from the [By-design restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#by-design-restrictions) section of the current EF Core documentation:

> - You cannot create a `DbSet<T>` for an owned type.
> - You cannot call `Entity<T>()` with an owned type on `ModelBuilder`.

Note that applying `IEnityTypeConfiguration<T>` class is equivalent of calling `Entity<T>()` on `ModelBuilder`.

So you are breaking both aforementioned restrictions.

What you need to do is

1. Remove the `DbSet<CreditCard>` property from the context
2. Remove `CreditCardTypeEntityTypeConfiguration` class and corresponding `ApplyConfiguration` call
3. Move the `CreditCard` configuration code inside the owner `JobSeeker` configuration using the builder provided/returned by the `OwnsMany` method. e.g.

```cs
jsConfiguration.OwnsMany(a => a.CreditCards, ccConfiguration =>
{
    // Build the model
    ccConfiguration.HasOne(o => o.CardType).WithMany().HasForeignKey("_creditCardTypeID");
    
    ccConfiguration.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
    ccConfiguration.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
});
```